# Find the value of $m+n$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We have 15 points on a circle with equal distance of two points that are next to each other. If $O$ is the center and $A,B$ are two of that points then the probability that prepedicular bisectors of $OA$ and $OB$ intersect inside is $\frac mn$ and $\gcd(m,n)=1$ then what is the value of $m+n$?

It was a test and I got the answer $\frac45$ which gives $m+n=9$.Am I right?

Comment: What do you mean, "perpendicular bisectors of OA and OB are inside"?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I meant intersect inside.

Comment: Can $A,B$ be the same point, and are two coincident lines considered to intersect in the circle?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel No they can't be same points and for the second one no.

Comment: Is an intersection point exactly on the circle considered inside?

Comment: I don't think we have sth such that because it is a special case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of symmetry we can fix one point and vary the other. Simple geometry shows that if the second point is less than five positions away, the intersections of the perpendicular bisectors will lie strictly within the circle, and there are eight points out of 14 that are as such. Thus the probability desired is $\frac8{14}=\frac47$ and $m+n=11$.